# working with 2d vector in cpp

Tags: c++, vector

My problem was:
I have 2d data that I want to store in a data structure. I don't know exact number of rows and columns in advance.
So,
I am using 2D vector.
I know (Anticipated) Maximum number of rows and columns.

1. I don't want to waste memory so can I use resize function? 
   Or
2. If I work with 1D vector and access it as 2D (e.g. vector[row *
       width + col]). How can I find width of my vector?

Comment: welcome to SO. It's not clear what's your problem. Yes you can use `resize`. Have you tried it? What was the problem?

Comment: as you don't want to waste memory, your anticipated max size is irrelevant here

Comment: Yeah but I was thinking to destroy unused space afterwards.

Comment: freeing vector's unused memory is a bit tricky. `resize` doesn't work as it just changes internal counter. you need to do something like `vec.swap(std::vector<...>(vec));`, just bear in mind it also copies all items

Answer (score 2):

About the way you're trying to access in your first option, it can't be done. You need to already have a value there before you can assign to it. The code below shows a contrived but functional solution and demonstration.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void add_element(vector<vector<int>> &data, int row, int col, int val)
{
    while (data.size() <= row) data.push_back(vector<int>());
    while (data[row].size() <= col) data[row].push_back(int());
    data[row][col] = val;
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> data;
    int col_idx = 0;
    cout << "Before...\n";
    cout << data.size() << " rows.\n\n";
    for (auto &row : data)
        cout << "row " << col_idx++ << ": " << row.size() << " columns.\n";
    add_element(data, 4, 5, 21);
    cout << "After...\n";
    col_idx = 0;
    cout << data.size() << " rows.\n\n";
    for (auto &row : data)
        cout << "row " << col_idx++ << ": " << row.size() << " columns.\n";
    cout << "\nAccess...\n";
    cout << "data[4][5] == " << data[4][5] << endl;
    data[4][5] = 99;
    data[2].push_back(33);
    data[2].push_back(41);
    data[2].push_back(55);
    cout << "data[2][2] == " << data[2][2] << endl;
    data[2][2] *= 2;
    cout << "data[2][2] == " << data[2][2] << endl;
    cout << "data[4][5] == " << data[4][5] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could make this a little more efficient by bulk allocating with `.resize()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::vector::reserve()` with `resize()` function to reserve the individual rows instead.

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > data;
data.resize(nMaxRows);
for(int i=0;i<nMaxRows;i++){
    data[i].reserve(nMaxColumn);
}
```

Comment: How to access elements in this scenario?

Comment: This does not resolve issue #1 -- all memory will be allocated up front anyways.

Comment: How to access elements (store and retrieve) in this scenario?

Comment: data[i][j] is not working. it is generating : vector subscript out of range exception.

Comment: it's working as supposed, the problem is that you're trying to access non-existing elements. Check you indices.

Comment: You've got to be sure that i < data.size() && j < data[i].size(), Remember this is zero-based indexing.

Comment: I am not accessing, rather I was storing using this notation. e.g. data[0][1] = 2;
It is necessary for me to store data by mentioning exact row and column so I can't use push_back method.

Comment: to access an item you first need to create that item, either by `push_back()` or by `resize()`. it's not working as in `std::map` case

Comment: So I cannot use the above approach? As I want to access and store elements by explicitly mentioning row and col number. And by push_back, I cannot do this.

Comment: did you search about c++ sparse matrices?

Comment: Actually I just started c++ programming, Is there any simple approach you guys can suggest?

Answer (score 0):

As for option 2, if you work with a 1-dimensional vector that represents a 2-dimensional, use a wrapper, like

```
class Vector2D{

    private:

        vector<int> m_data;
        unsigned int m_width;
        unsigned int m_height;

        unsigned int index_transformation((const unsigned int i, const unsigned int j) const;

    public:

        Vector2D(const int default_value = 0);
        Vector2D(const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height, const int default_value = 0);

        void resize(const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height);

        int& operator() (const unsigned int i, const unsigned int j);
        const int& operator() (const unsigned int i, const unsigned int j) const;

        const unsigned int& width() const;
        const unsigned int& height() const;
}
```

(private done first in my example for you to easily understand the structure)

Point is, width first or height first is pretty much arbitrary and the responsibility how this is done should lie at one single place, like within a wrapper. In this case, it is even reduced to a single method, index_transformation.

edit: Andy T asked me why I favor this structure, thing is, I don't. Basically, I'm saying **if** you do it like that, then... But you can easily go with a `vector<vector<int> >` instead, no problems there. That said, you might also want to wrap a 2d-vector, for the simple reason that this can make sure that the vector stays regular (unlike {{1,2},{3}} for example, which has a subvector of length 2 and one of length 1) - that is, if the vector is passed around a lot. A simple 2d-vector is totally fine within a small scope or within any context that can easily assure regularity.

That said, for your problem in general: Most likely, initialization won't hurt. That is, you can simply initialize your vector with the anticipated amount of elements (or, better said, the upper border of that). This will of course cause a workload in O(n), but most likely, this workload will be small compared with the workload that comes afterwards. If it is not, because your anticipation can be far bigger than the actual usage or if only a few actions are done in the later algorithm, yeah, go with reserve, no problem here. Disadvantage is that you still need to resize the vector which you can forget, but that is easy to detect.

Comment: why do you think flat vector is better that `vector<vector<T>>`?

Comment: @AndyT Good question. Actually I don't, I'm more or less saying *if* he takes option 2, then he should it like that. But yeah, gonna do an edit.

Answer (score 0):

after come discussions in comments seems the problem is accessing 2D vector items when they can not exist yet.

To set an item with arbitrary indices:

```
template <typename T>
void set(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& vec, size_t i, size_t j, T const& val)
{
    if (vec.size() <= i)
        vec.resize(i + 1);
    auto&& row = vec[i];
    if (row.size() <= j)
        row.resize(j + 1);
    row[j] = val;
}
```

To get an item, you need to decide what behaviour you want: to throw an exception when the item doesn't exist or to create it with some default value and return.

You asked about freeing unused memory. You can free only memory at the end of vector as all its items are stored in a single memory block one after another. If your data structure is sparse (with lots of gaps) `vector` is not the best candidate. The simplest solution would be to emulate a sparse container by a `map`, e.g. `std::map<size_t, std::map<size_t, T>>`. In this case when you do

```
map[i][j] = val;
```

even if an item at `(i, j)` place didn't exist before it will be created on demand. To free unused memory you need to delete items from the map by `std::map<Key, Value>::erase(key)` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Matrix:

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Matrix {

public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef vector<T> row_t;
    // ctor
    Matrix(){}  
    Matrix(int rows, int cols){
        for (int i = 0; i<rows; ++i){
            mat.push_back(row_t(cols));
        }
    }
    Matrix(int rows, int cols, const initializer_list<T>& l){
        for (int i = 0; i<rows; ++i){
            mat.push_back(row_t(cols));
        }
        auto it = l.begin();
        int y=0, x=0;
        while (it != l.end()){
            mat[y][x++] = *it++;
            if (x == cols){
                ++y;
                x = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    Matrix(const Matrix<T>& m){
        for (auto e : m.mat){
            mat.push_back(e);
        }
    }
    // method
    int getRowCount(){
        return mat.size();
    }

    int getColumnCount(){
        if (mat.size() == 0)
            return 0;
        return mat[0].size();
    }

    row_t& operator[](int n){
        if ( n<0 || static_cast<size_t>(n) >= mat.size() ){
            ostringstream oss;
            oss << "bad index " << n << " out of range [0.." << mat.size() << "]";
            throw runtime_error(oss.str());
        }
        return mat[n];
    }

    Matrix<T>& operator=(const Matrix<T>& m){
        if (&m != this){
            mat.clear();
            for (auto e : m.mat){
                mat.push_back(e);
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

private:
    vector<row_t> mat;

};

#endif // MATRIX_H
```